# Create DataFrame grouping columns in map type

Tags: python, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My **DataFrame** has the following structure:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('B', 'a', 10),
     ('B', 'b', 20),
     ('C', 'c', 30)],
    ['Brand', 'Type', 'Amount'])
df.show()
# +-----+----+------+
# |Brand|Type|Amount|
# +-----+----+------+
# |    B|   a|    10|
# |    B|   b|    20|
# |    C|   c|    30|
# +-----+----+------+
```

I want to reduce the amount of rows by grouping `type` and `amount` into one single column of *type*: `Map`.
So `Brand` will be unique and `MAP_type_AMOUNT` will have `key,value` for each `type` `amount` combination.

I think, spark.sql might have some functions to do it, or do I have to use RDD and make my "own" conversion to map type?

**Expected output**:

```
---------------------------
| Brand | MAP_type_AMOUNT |
---------------------------
|  B    |  {a: 10, b:20}  |
|  C    |  {c: 30}        |
---------------------------
```

Comment: I don't think we have something like rdd's collectAsmap in dataframe. Better you can use own conversion function.

Answer (score 10):

Slight improvement to [Prem's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45532183/pyspark-create-dataframe-grouping-columns-in-map-type-structure/45535762#45535762) answer (sorry I can't comment yet)

Use `func.create_map` instead of `func.struct`. See [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=map#pyspark.sql.functions.create_map)

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
df = sc.parallelize([('B','a',10),('B','b',20),
('C','c',30)]).toDF(['Brand','Type','Amount'])

df_converted = df.groupBy("Brand").\
    agg(func.collect_list(func.create_map(func.col("Type"),
    func.col("Amount"))).alias("MAP_type_AMOUNT"))

print df_converted.collect()
```

Output:

```
[Row(Brand=u'B', MAP_type_AMOUNT=[{u'a': 10}, {u'b': 20}]),
 Row(Brand=u'C', MAP_type_AMOUNT=[{u'c': 30}])]
```

Comment: Perfect improvement :)

Comment: @osbon123 How can we do the reverse? convert map-type to multiple column dataframe?

Comment: This doesn't generate a dict but instead it generate an array of dict, each one with only one key and value pair.

Answer (score 7):

Using `collect_list` and `map_from_arrays` together can achieve this

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_converted = (
    df.groupBy('Brand')
    .agg(
        F.collect_list('type').alias('type'),
        F.collect_list('amount').alias('amount'),
    )
    .withColumn('MAP_type_AMOUNT', F.map_from_arrays('type', 'amount'))
    .drop('type', 'amount')
)
```

Output

```
+-----+------------------+
|Brand|   MAP_type_AMOUNT|
+-----+------------------+
|    C|         [c -> 30]|
|    B|[b -> 20, a -> 10]|
+-----+------------------+
```

Comment: Having a true big data, is there a guarantee that both `collect_list` will have the same record order so that `map_from_arrays` can generate correct maps? I mean, when you have window functions, you specify the order column, but when you use `agg`, there's no such thing, so it seems to me, that there's no guarantee for the order of values inside both arrays. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, it guarantee the order. I tested this on true big data and don't see any inconsistent. I think only the `groupBy` (which involves repartition by hash function) will mess up the order. The `agg` don't mess up the order. Even the `groupBy` mess up the order, it still won't give you a row with the `type` not matching the `amount`.

Answer (score 4):

You can have something like below but not exactly 'Map'

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
df = sc.parallelize([('B','a',10),('B','b',20),('C','c',30)]).toDF(['Brand','Type','Amount'])

df_converted = df.groupBy("Brand").\
    agg(func.collect_list(func.struct(func.col("Type"), func.col("Amount"))).alias("MAP_type_AMOUNT"))
df_converted.show()
```

Output is:

```
+-----+----------------+
|Brand| MAP_type_AMOUNT|
+-----+----------------+
|    B|[[a,10], [b,20]]|
|    C|        [[c,30]]|
+-----+----------------+
```

Comment: This is not what OP wanted. Instead of map, this generates an array of struct.

Answer (score 2):

This is a working approach to create map from separate columns:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_converted = df.groupBy('Brand').agg(
    F.map_from_entries(F.collect_set(F.struct('Type', 'Amount'))).alias('MAP_type_AMOUNT')
)

df_converted.show()
# +-----+------------------+
# |Brand|   MAP_type_AMOUNT|
# +-----+------------------+
# |    B|{b -> 20, a -> 10}|
# |    C|         {c -> 30}|
# +-----+------------------+
```

Comment: This output is closest to what the OP stated under "Expected Output". Considering that the OP asked for type "Map" and spark uses `->` instead of `:` this answer is exactly what is expected from the original post.